# add namespace to your javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javascript-namespaces

I have worked on google map api few years ago and wrote a little reusable utility. At that time adding google map api reference does add all the api classses in your page's global namespace. As this is working sample

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?SOMEPARAMETERS">
<script>
var map= new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var point= new LatLng(31,75);
var line= new Polyline(OPTIONS);
</script>
```

In v3, all Google Maps JavaScript API code is stored in the google.maps.* namespace instead of the global namespace. Most objects have also been renamed as part of this process and some more changes are done.

Now you have to write the above code as follows

```
<script src="APIURL">
<script>
var map= new google.map.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var point= new google.mapLatLng(31,75);
var line= new google.map.Polyline(OPTIONS);
</script>
```

**ISSUE**

I wrote a library back in Google v2  API time and used in number of projects and was working great. But now I am working on a new project and using Google V3 API and want to reuse that old v2 library. But adding v3 library doesn't add the API classes in global namespace and my library doesn't work. Is there any way we can add namespace to our JavaScript file like we did in C# on top and it allows us to write the classes without appending the namespace

Comment: The third version of the maps API uses different methods with new method names, so even if you could namespace your javascript like that (which you can't) you'd have to change all the names, parameters etc. to match the new API, so you're probably better of just rewriting your library.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to just use references:

```
(function() { // A scoping function to avoid creating glboals
    var GMap2 = google.map.Map;
    var LatLng = google.map.LatLng;
    var Polyline = googlemap.Polyline;


    // ...your code using the above here...
})();
```

This assumes, though, that the arguments haven't changed.

Alternately, you could use the Facade pattern:

```
function GMap2(/*...relevant args...*/)

    return new google.map.Map(/*...relevant args here, possibly modified...*/);
}
```

(And similar for others.)

(That works even if you use `new` with `GMap2` because the result of the `new` expression will be the object you return from the constructor function if you return an object.)